# Jquery and CSS image centering not working in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with my image centering in jquery tab. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jtifF)** from codepen.io . If you click my DEMO page then you see 1.Tab , 2.Tab and 3.Tab and there is 1.Tab is active. 1.Tab image centering is working but if you click 2.Tab and 3.Tab then you see image centering is not working. What i need to do here anyone can help me ?

I am using this css code for img:

```
.img {
    float:left;
    width:310px;
    height:180px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }       
.img img {
 width:100%; 
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.img:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

**Not**: *I think this is not css problem.*

Comment: It's a CSS problem. You've got styles directly on those `<img>` tags (like `left: 155px`) that are moving the image away from where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `tabify` plugin hides the list elements (which includes the images) of all inactive tabs. So when you're measuring the images for calculating the right position, the image dimensions are `(0,0)`.

A workaround for this is to **wait till all images have been loaded** and after that apply the `tabify` plugin.

This is what I mean:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  var $imgs = $('.img img'),
      count = $imgs.length,
      counter = 0;

  $imgs
    .imgCentering({'forceSmart':true})
    .load(function() {
      counter++;
      if(counter === count) {
        $('#magtabs_').tabify(); 
      }

    })

})
```

*You better should use the event handlers you've already defined in your `imgCentering` function. This code snippet works, but it is only a example of how it could be fixed.*

Here is the working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FKzHx)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a script for centering but the thing is, it's only getting the right value for the active one and 0 for the others. This messes up the computation of the left and top values. So it's more of a loading issue...

Comment: yes you are right. I try with `live()` and `delegate()` - I was testing them.if i click 2.Tab or 3.Tab then tab links disappeared.